# Children free under 5 on UK trains -- any need to prove?

Tags: uk, trains

I've got a a 4-year-old who's in school, and is quite big for their age.  I've just booked a train journey, paying only for myself and relying on the fact that under 5s travel free (though [quite possibly without a seat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/114151/18491)).

Is there ever a need to prove that the child is under 5 when relying on the free ticket (and if so how)?  I'd rather not have to carry their birth certificate as it's a valuable document that won't fit in my wallet and travelling by train with a small person (and all their stuff) isn't easy without another valuable item to worry about. On the other hand I don't want any awkwardness from an overzealous official.  I haven't been able to find anything obvious on the train companies' websites.

Comment: Does the UK have compact birth certificate summaries?  We have them in Canada, and they're as valid as the full-sized original.  If so, get one of those.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie they're not exactly compact (they're known as "short form").  These days they're not all that common as they're not  accepted in questions of nationality

Comment: Ours are driver's-license sized.  Sounds like yours are very different.  Perhaps then a photocopy, perhaps notarized?  You could then fold it up and put it in your pocket.  Better safe than sorry.

Comment: simply take a photo of the birth certificate with your smartphone.

Comment: @Aganju I might well do that, but "proof" and "photo on phone" don't really have much in common.  If however actual proof isn't necessary (as user16259 answers below) it could be handy.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Notarising a copy of a birth certificate is probably going to cost more than just buying a child ticket. It's also pointless.

Comment: @MJeffryes is right, especially as that's not really done in the UK (getting a duplicate certificate is more common)

Comment: @MJeffryes Of course technically anyone travelling on a child ticket might need to carry proof of age https://www.southernrailway.com/help-and-support/contact-us/faqs/tickets

Comment: @origimbo perhaps you'd like to add an answer pointing to that page, though their wording is "child fare" not "child ticket" and there's room for debate about whether a fare of zero counts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in the rail national conditions of carriage about documentary proof either. It only specifies that they can't occupy a seat if it is needed by a ticket holder.

Anecdotally, I've had guards question the ages of children but not demand any documents.

Comment: An old method, which likely still works, is asking the children themselves and only question the parents when the child gives an age which is over the limit.